# a variant of the Kleene tree

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, trees

The (a?) Kleene tree is a computable (a.k.a. decidable) sub-tree of the full binary tree with no computable path. It is well-known.

I need a variant. (For those in the know, I need a c-bar which is not a D-bar.) What I need is also based on a computable labeling of the binary tree. With the Kleene tree, once a binary sequence gets kicked off the tree, all of its descendants are kicked off too, else it wouldn’t be a tree. So you can think of a Kleene tree as a computable labeling of binary sequences by “in” and “out”, where once a sequence is “out” so are all of its descendants. In the tree I need, if a sequence is labeled “out,” a descendant is allowed to be labeled “in”. A sequence is really off the tree when it AND all of its descendants are labeled “out”. This is a $\Pi^0_1$ condition, hence not computable  (at least, not obviously computable). A sequence is in the tree when some descendant is labeled “in”.

What I need is a tree like that, with no computable paths, not equal to any Kleene tree. Anyone know one? Or how to do it? Presumably some priority argument would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K_s$ be a computable monotone sequence of finite sets whose union is $K$, the halting set. Let $T$ be the tree of all $\{0,1\}$-sequences $\tau$ such that for some $s \geq |\tau|$, $\tau$ is the characteristic function of $K_s \cap \{0,\ldots,|\tau|-1\}$. The tree $T$ is of the type you want and its only infinite path is the characteristic function of $K$. $T$ cannot be a Kleene-type tree because of the Low Basis Theorem.

Comment: Thanks Francois. This probably suffices for my ultimate use. I still find it odd that there's this example with just one path. The regular Kleene tree has lots of paths. I wonder whether there's an example (of the type I asked for) that looks more like the Kleene tree, bushier, with continuum many paths.

Comment: @RobertLubarsky Easily arranged! Given a tree $T$, let $\hat{T}=\{\sigma: (\sigma(0), \sigma(2), \sigma(4), . . . , \sigma(2k), . . )\in T\}$; then every path through $\hat{T}$ computes a path through $T$, and $\hat{T}$ is of the same complexity as $T$, but $\hat{T}$ has continuum-many paths.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma_i=0...01$ ($i$ many $0$s). We can build a $\Pi^0_1$ tree $T$ such that $\sigma_i\in T$ iff the $i$th c.e. tree either does not contain $\sigma_i$, or eventually kills all extensions of $\sigma_i$; this involves killing $\sigma_i$ at first if $\sigma_i$ appears on the $i$th computable tree, then perhaps bringing back $\sigma_i$ at a later date. Meanwhile, above each $\sigma_i$ we don't kill (or do bring back), we repeat the usual construction of an infinite computable tree with no computable paths.

Comment: I can't get off the ground with this answer. The problem I have with it is right up  front: what is the $i$th computable tree? I know what the $i$ computable function is, and the $i$ c.e. set. But given a program, I can't tell whether it determines a computable set or not.

Comment: @RobertLubarsky Sorry, I should have said "$i$th c.e. tree." The point is, for a fixed Turing machine $\Phi_i$, I keep $\sigma_i$ on the tree I'm building - until $\Phi_i(\sigma_i)\downarrow=1$ (as well as for every predecessor of $\sigma_i$). then I kill $\sigma_i$, and only bring it back if for some $n$, I see $\Phi_i(\tau)\downarrow=0$ for every extension $\tau$ of $\sigma_i$ of length $n$.

Comment: I finally understand your construction. It seems to work. Thanks. Also for your comment on my comment on Francois's answer. Honestly, wasn't that hard. I feel dumb.

Comment: Wait a minute. The 0 sequence is a computable path through your tree.